# Game Center submission method causing nil optional unwrap error

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, option-type

I'm working on adding GameCenter support to my app. I have the following method in my view controller

```
func submitToGC(newScore: Int) {
    // Submit score to GC leaderboard
    let bestScoreInt = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: LEADERBOARD_ID)
    bestScoreInt.value = Int64(newScore)
    GKScore.report([bestScoreInt]) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

When called with any value, the code generates the "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value" error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: * Sigh * Why does nobody read the documentation? There is a method `integer(forKey` which can never cause a crash

Comment: How is the `viewController` variable defined?

Comment: @Losiowaty var viewController : GameViewController!
also, other parts of the GameScene file use it without a problem

Comment: You don't need to start the title with tags; that's what the tags are for.

Comment: Still - did you check here that it is not the one causing an issue? Have you tried debugging with breakpoints and inspecting variable values?

Comment: @JoshCaswell gotchu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to instantiate a GameViewController and then call its methods with that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `if let` to unwrap the optional instead of force unwrapping it?

```
if let highestScore = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "HighestScore") as? Int{
   viewController.submitToGC(newScore: highestScore)
}
```

Comment: It's not a force unwrap, it's a force cast.

Answer (score 0):

If submitToGC is defined in the same class you don't need to use `viewController.submitToGC` to call the function, you can just use `submitToGC`. Also it is best to unwrap the variable first and then put that value into the function like this:

```
if let value = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "HighestScore") as Int {
   submitToGC(newScore: value) 
}
```